# Is there a way I can generate a class with all the properties obtained from a List<string>?

Tags: c#

I have a List object. In the code, I want to declare a new class , and its attributes, which are dynamically generated, are all obtained from the List object. Is there a way I can do this?

For example: I have a `List<string> lstStr= "apple, pear, banana";` and I want to generate a new class in the code:

```
Class Foo{
   string apple;
   string pear;
   string banana;
}
```

Comment: How do you plan on *using* the object you create?

Comment: I will create a bunch of objects to put in a List and bind to a Datagrid for display.

Answer (score 0):

I would use another collection like [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) instead:

```
Dictionary<String, String> Foo = lstStr
                           .Distinct()
                           .ToDictionary(f => f, f => default(String));
// now you can get/set the elements in the following way:
String banana = Foo["banana"];
Foo["apple"] = "some apple";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a class then this might be something you can do using codedom - either parse the string into a class definition string and generate from there, or use the list of strings to create the properties as you loop through them.

Theres a guide to the basics [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thottams/archive/2006/08/16/701872.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using c# 4 or higher you can do this with dynamics and specifically the ExpandoObject.

```
    var x = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;
foreach (var prop in lstStr)
{
     x.Add(prop, "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
public static List<Foo> GetFooList() { .... }
```

or extend from the List Object but many methods are virtual so you may not end up with all the methods.

```
public class FooList:List<Foo> { .... //add more }
```

and using it

```
public static FooList GetFooList() { .... }
```

link:
[C# Generics : List<Object> or new class extends List <Object>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630617/c-sharp-generics-listobject-or-new-class-extends-list-object)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have said in comments that your end goal here is to bind the data to a `DataGrid` I'd suggest that you use a `DataTable`.  You can create a blank slate, add columns (of any primitive type) and then populate any number of rows all with that same column schema.  Additionally, you can trivially bind the `DataTable` to a `DataGrid`; they were designed to work together.